# wxPython - Feedback while switching between panels

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, user-experience, wxwidgets

I have a splitter window with a list box on the left and a panel on the right. When I click on an item in the listbox, the panel changes to a panel that is specific to that item. Many of these panels look similar by design, and are all generated from the same class with settings taken from the item.

I would like to add some sort of feedback so the user can tell that something has changed. Something basic, like the panel switching to empty panel for a fraction of a second, and then switching to the new panel would suffice.

Do you have any suggestions on the best way to do this? Does wx have a feature that already handles this or something similar? Will I just have to do exactly what I outlined above, if so, if there a recommended time to display the blank panel? I could play around with timing to find what I feel is right, but I'm sure there has been studies into simple concepts like this. I may end up choosing a delay that is too quick and most users may miss it, but it may seem normal to me as I am the one testing it. I may prefer shorter delays so I can test more quickly, and my opinion will be biased.

Comment: There are lots of simple approaches. Make the panels different by giving them different background colors. Or add a label/title to each page that is unique. Or change the title that's in the frame to indicate that you're viewing something different.

Comment: The number of items in the list is arbitrary. I could have 50 items. Changing the background color would involve strategically setting colors that are both good looking and different. You could alternate colors, but then still half the choices will look similar. I do have a label/title, but I the change isn't that noticeable. Perhaps I could make it bigger, but I don't won't it to be obtrusive and I don't think it will significantly help notice the change.

Comment: The color changing could work by just passing the previous color along. Then you could have a check that would prevent it from changing to that color.

Comment: I do like that idea, assuming I can make it work with the style without appearing out of place. I am still open to all other suggestions as well